# how are methods and inheritances handled in .NET service applications

Tags: vb.net, dll, service

I am write a serivce application that writes values from a string sent over a com port. the app works in a winform type of app. but if i make a service application and add the classes and copy and paste the code in, it fails when it tries to inherit a DBConnection method in a dll reference. if i comment the below out it installs correctly. do service application handle reference calls in a certain way?

```
Public Class BondSQLConnection
Inherits PCA.Core.Database.DBConnection

Public Sub New(ByVal DefaultDatabase As String)
    MyBase.New(DBConnectionType.SQLServer,
               String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={3};User Id={1};Password={2};", "SQLSERVER", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "MYDATABASE"), DefaultDatabase)

  End Sub
End Class
```

i have noticed on our server with other service application they only have the one exe file. no dependency files at all in the folder. [PIC of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q58jd.png)

Installing assembly 'C:\Users\GEL8953\Desktop\TEST\BondTestService\BondTestService\bin\Debug\BondTestService.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole = 
   assemblypath = C:\Users\GEL8953\Desktop\TEST\BondTestService\BondTestService\bin\Debug\BondTestService.exe
   logfile = C:\Users\GEL8953\Desktop\TEST\BondTestService\BondTestService\bin\Debug\BondTestService.InstallLog
An exception occurred while trying to find the installers in the C:\Users\GEL8953\Desktop\TEST\BondTestService\BondTestService\bin\Debug\BondTestService.exe assembly.
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
Aborting installation for C:\Users\GEL8953\Desktop\TEST\BondTestService\BondTestService\bin\Debug\BondTestService.exe.
Rolling back assembly 'C:\Users\GEL8953\Desktop\TEST\BondTestService\BondTestService\bin\Debug\BondTestService.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole = 
   assemblypath = C:\Users\GEL8953\Desktop\TEST\BondTestService\BondTestService\bin\Debug\BondTestService.exe
   logfile = C:\Users\GEL8953\Desktop\TEST\BondTestService\BondTestService\bin\Debug\BondTestService.InstallLog
An exception occurred while trying to find the installers in the C:\Users\GEL8953\Desktop\TEST\BondTestService\BondTestService\bin\Debug\BondTestService.exe assembly.
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
Aborting installation for C:\Users\GEL8953\Desktop\TEST\BondTestService\BondTestService\bin\Debug\BondTestService.exe.

Comment: Have you added a reference to that library to your project?

Comment: It's possible that the dependency is bundled or is a global reference. Can you post the error message text?

Comment: @rory.ap- the reference (PCA.CORE) is added to our references list. and im not to sure if its bundles or global but yes i will post the pic of the error, one sec.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of the error, please paste the text of the error.  Also, I looked at the picture and it tells you to look in a log file for the details of the exception.  Those are the details we are asking to see.  Please paste in the text of the exception from the log file.

Comment: sure, i posted the error log contents